# How to use SQL to sort a column by the first group of digits that appears in each row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Is there a way to use SQL to sort a column by the first group of digits that appears in the column?

For example, the column contains values like so:

```
PPP-26-8
PPP-29-8
PPP-216-8
PPP-220
PPP-236
```

Only the first group of digits is to be considered for sorting in increasing numerical order, i.e. 26, 29, 216, 220, 236

I currently have something like this, which kind of works, but gives me warnings:

```
CAST(RIGHT(model, LENGTH(model) - 4) as UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Warning, specifically is this:

> Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '216-8'

**Update**

It seems like this will do it, where `-` is the delimiter:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '-', 2), '-', -1) as UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: Yes, you can sort it in any way you like, but the performance will be terrible unless you create an index based on the same sorting base. What warnings do you get? Post them in your question.

Comment: Unless this is a once a week query on a table not growing, you should extract the number you want to sort on to another column and index it.

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean by `Only the first group of digits is to be considered for sorting in increasing numerical order.`?

Comment: I updated question to show the warning I get, and I mean that the column is to be sorted by placing the numbers inside the values in increasing order: 26, 29, 216, 220, 236, to where these numbers appear after the first dash, and the trailing number after the second dash is to not be considered for sorting

Comment: The warning is clear, you're not extracting the digits correctly, so you have non-digits (i.e. the hyphen) included which gives the warning when you try to cast it. After you use `RIGHT` to eliminate the prefix, you need to remove the suffix too before you cast.

Answer (score 3):

You could use string function to get string after first - and * 1 for type casting

```
select *
from demo
order by substring_index(substring_index(col,'-',2),'-',-1) * 1
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f2e42/3)

Comment: Be explicit. Use the `CAST` operator for readability instead of `* 1`.

Comment: @SalmanA I agree cast should be used for such conversions http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f2e42/9

Comment: @SalmanA Just wondering, why did you not post the same comment to Gordon's answer which you edited? Yes, he's 622k, but very kind and will reply politely, I promise :).

Comment: @RacilHilan didn't notice the alternate solution at that time.

Comment: @SalmanA You edited and corrected it. How do you correct something without noticing it? Are you on auto-pilot? :).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always mean the second group (as defined by the "-"), then you can use `substring_index()`.  If they always begin with "P-", you can do:

```
order by length(substring_index(model, '-', 2)),
         substring_index(model, '-', 2)
```

If the initial part can be of variable length, go fo:

```
order by substring_index(substring_index(model, '-', 2), '-', -1) + 0
```

The `+ 0` converts the value to a number, for ordering purposes.  The use `+ 0` for conversion uses *silent conversion* in MySQL.  That is, it does not generate an error when the string is non-numeric.  Instead, it just treats such strings as a value of "0".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '-', 2), '-', -1);
```

If you want this to use an index, you'll have to create a virtual column and an index on the virtual column (this works in MySQL 5.7 and later).

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ADD COLUMN model_second_number AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '-', 2), '-', -1)+0),
  ADD KEY (model_second_number);
```

Then you have an opportunity to sort by that index:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY model_second_number;
```